# Extract value from property array in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have something like this:

```
MATCH (a)-[rel]->(b), x  
WHERE x.id = rel.allIds.contains(5)  
RETURN x
```

where the rel.allIds is an array of numbers.

How can I make the *contains* query in cypher?

*Note:* I'm using Neo4j 2.1.5 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ANY` to check each ID to see if it's equal.

```
MATCH (a)-[rel]->(b), x
WHERE has(x.id) and ANY(someid IN rel.allIds WHERE someid = x.id)
RETURN x
```

This goes through all items in `rel.allIds`, binds each to `someid` and then checks to see if it's the same as X's id.

More broadly though, that extra `x` in your match matches anything in the graph.  I'm guessing you have a very small graph, because matching in this way is highly inefficient.  You might want to create a node for that relationship instead, and then link it to x, because this is not a query you'll want to run frequently.

Comment: That did the job, thank you! Also thanks for your advice about the x thing, I will have it in mind for the future.